# Transform dataframe value to range value in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, transform, transformation

I have a dataframe with the values:

```
3.05
35.97
49.11
48.80
48.02
10.61
25.69
6.02 
55.36
0.42
47.87
2.26
54.43
8.85 
8.75
14.29
41.29
35.69
44.27
1.08
```

I want transform the value into range and give new value to each value.
From the df we know the min value is 0.42 and the max value is 55.36.
From range min to max, I want divide to 4 group which is:

```
0.42  - 14.15 transform to 1 
14.16 - 27.88 transform to 2
27.89 - 41.61 transform to 3
41.62 - 55.36 transform to 4
```

so the result I expected is

```
1
3
4
4
4
1
2
1
4
1
4
1
4
1
1
2
3
3
4
1
```

Comment: You are looking at binning, the function to use is `pd.cut()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally called binning, but pandas calls it `cut`.  Sample code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of numbers, with a header called "nums"
data_list = [('nums', [3.05, 35.97, 49.11, 48.80, 48.02, 10.61, 25.69, 6.02, 55.36, 0.42, 47.87, 2.26, 54.43, 8.85, 8.75, 14.29, 41.29, 35.69, 44.27, 1.08])]

# Create the labels for the bin
bin_labels = [1,2,3,4]

# Create the dataframe object using the data_list
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(data_list)

# Define the scope of the bins
bins = [0.41, 14.16, 27.89, 41.62, 55.37]

# Create the "bins" column using the cut function using the bins and labels
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['nums'], bins=bins, labels=bin_labels)
```

This creates a dataframe which has the following structure:

```
print(df)

     nums bins
0    3.05    1
1   35.97    3
2   49.11    4
3   48.80    4
4   48.02    4
5   10.61    1
6   25.69    2
7    6.02    1
8   55.36    4
9    0.42    1
10  47.87    4
11   2.26    1
12  54.43    4
13   8.85    1
14   8.75    1
15  14.29    2
16  41.29    3
17  35.69    3
18  44.27    4
19   1.08    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a function like the following to have full control over the process:

```
def transform(l):
    l2 = []
    for i in l:
        if 0.42 <= i <= 14.15:
            l2.append(1)
        elif i <= 27.8:
            l2.append(2)
        elif i <= 41.61:
            l2.append(3)
        elif i <= 55.36:
            l2.append(4)
    return(l2)

df['nums'] = transform(df['nums'])
```